# Python toolbox field value precision - selection based on Double field

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-toolbox, double, precision-scale

I have a python toolbox (.pyt) where the user selects a layer, a field from that layer and then values from that field. The tool uses this to make a selection based on the field values. It's working fine for all other datatypes (integer, text/string, float) but there is an issue with double that I think I've narrowed down to precision.

Manually making the selection by attribute the field value is 0.1000000014901162 (works). The value displayed in the tool is 0.100000001490116 (see image).
[image]

The field is data type double with a precision of 0 and scale of 0 (see image).
[image]
I would like a solution that will work across any precision/scale. I've tried using python's [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), but that gives too high a precision 0.100000001490116119384765. This one selection is part of a very long script but I've disassembled the functions and here are the relevant bits (not indented/functional):

```
    #def getParameterInfor(self):
    # FC
    landUse = arcpy.Parameter("Landuse/Greenspace Polygons",
                              "land_use", "GpFeatureLayer", "Optional", "Input")
    # Field
    LULC_field = arcpy.Parameter("Greenspace Field", "LULCFld", "Field", 
                                 "Optional", "Input")
    # List of fields from table
    landVal = arcpy.Parameter("Greenspace Field Values", "grn_field_val", 
                              "GPString", "Optional", "Input", multiValue=True)

    LULC_field.parameterDependencies = [landUse.name]
    landVal.parameterDependencies = [LULC_field.name]
    landVal.filter.type = 'ValueList'

    #def updateParameters(self, p):
    # Conditions must be met for each input to become active
    if True in [p[4].value, p[6].value]:
        p[17].enabled = True
    else:
        p[17].enabled = False
    if p[17].altered:
        p[18].enabled = True
    if p[18].altered:
        in_poly = p[17].valueAsText
        TypeField = p[18].valueAsText
        p[19].enabled = True
        p[19].filter.list = unique_values(in_poly, TypeField)

    #def main()
    landuse = params[17].valueAsText
    field = params[18].valueAsText
    fieldLst = params[19].values

    # Convert the list of unicode to float
    fieldLst = map(float, fieldLst)

    # Make selection
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(landuse, "lyr")
    # Create where clause from list
    exp =''
    for item in fieldLst:
         if type(item) == float:
              exp += '"{}" = {} OR '.format(field, float(item))
    whereClause = exp[:-4]
    sel = "NEW_SELECTION"
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", sel, whereClause)
```

I haven't included all the code to differentiate datatypes, but the above currently works on float and other datatypes are differentiated either when converting from unicode or when creating a where clause from the list.

Comment: I'd use truncate, search Python sites

Comment: Truncating would work if values in the fieldLst were too long. The problem here is selecting features using a truncated value. The field's values could be queried, truncated and then written to a new field to use for selection, but that seems excessive, considering this is a limited issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of solving the problem in python, [ROUND()](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm) allows you to make the sql selection based on a field value rounded to a specified decimal place. exp then becomes:

```
 exp += 'ROUND({},{}) = {} OR '.format(field, dec_place, repr(item))
```

where dec_place is the number of decimal places:

```
dec_place = len(repr(item).split(".")[1])
```

[repr()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) was important as str() may round item further if performed on a float(). I chose to restrict this to instances where dec_place >= 15 (since in the OP that seems to be the .pyt cut off) foreseeing instances where rounding in the selection could cause unintended problems.